# How to transfer the product thumbnail to the right side in Porto Theme 2.1.0 magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm new to magento 2, I'm having hard time transferring the product thumbnail below the product image to the right side. I have attached a screenshot to be more clearer.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please also mention ur Purchased Theme URL if any

Comment: Porto 2.1.0 for magento 2

Comment: same i want to this any solutions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do this you will need to make 2 changes:

1) Edit XML

2) Edit CSS

---

1) Find the file "app/design/frontend/[Your_Theme]/[Your_Theme]/etc/view.xml" and look for these lines:

```
<Vars module="Magento_Catalog">

         <!- Gallery and magnifier theme settings. Start ->
         <Var name="gallery">
```

In this place it is possible to make many alterations in the gallery.

Edit the line:

```
<Var name="navdir">horizontal</var>
```

For:

```
<Var name="navdir">vertical</var>
```

---

2) Create or edit the file "app/design/frontend/[Your_Theme]/[Your_Theme]/web/css/source/_extend.less"

Add in the end:

```
.fotorama__nav-wrap--vertical {
    &.fotorama__nav-wrap {
        right: 0;
        left: inherit;
    }
}
.fotorama__stage {
    left: 0 !important;
}
```

Now compile your theme!

Comment: Hi Kaue M, Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution and it also worked in my end. Thanks again. keep sharing

Comment: Then see if it exists in the file: app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/etc/view.xml at line 200.

Comment: You can check here the original version of the file if you changed at any time: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/etc/view.xml at line 200

Comment: How to show right side thumbnail image, if this css added in extend.less inside

Comment: The css extend.less file is imported as one of the last items to compile the css, so by adding this CSS rule to the extend.less file and compiling, the resulting file will have this css rule at the end (which will have more relevance for be read by the browser).

Answer (score 2):

It's better to play with CSS i suggest

Code will be here **vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\gallery.phtml**

Reference Demo: http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/56098.html

```
<div class="fotorama__nav-wrap fotorama__nav-wrap--horizontal" data-gallery-role="nav-wrap">

</div>
```

Go to **magento2/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/gallery/gallery.css**

```
.fotorama__wrap{
 position: absolute:
 left: XXX;
 top: XXX;
 right: XXX:
}
```

You have to also define width

```
<div class="fotorama__nav fotorama__nav--thumbs" style="height: 114px; width: 707px;">
</div>
```

& it's CSS class

```
.fotorama__wrap {
}
```

Comment: @MazeStricks i have just given suggestion. Please post ur answer how u achieve this, so it will be helpful for community

Comment: I tried your suggestion. and I think for me it's applicable.

Comment: Good to hear @MazeStricks

Comment: do you know how to edit in porto theme 2.1.0? thanks